# How to communicate with arduino uno when arduino motor shield connected to arduino uno?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-motor-shield

I'm using this Dual Motor Shield
[image: L293D Arduino Dual Motor Shield]

when I plug Arduino Dual Motor Shield into Aruino uno can't seen any way to communicate with Adruino uno.how can I communicate with uno ?

Comment: What "communication" are you talking about? Do you mean "plug wires into D0-D13, A0-A5 pins of the Arduino UNO (in this case that would not be called communication) or USB communication to your PC, or ICSP communication with a programmer?

Comment: plug wires into D0-D13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Communicate with what? A PC? The usb serial port should still work fine, and anything connected to the RX/tx pins (D0 and  D1)
If your concern is that there is no longer a socket on the top of this shield that you can plug wires into, well you can solder on some wires to the top of the board, or you could get a screw shield board to go between the arduino and motor shield which would make all the pins available. I have also use small gauage wire wrapped around the shield pins and then just insert the shield onto the arduino making kind of a wire wrap connection between the boards.

Comment: i need to plug wires into D0-D13